# access xml part from c++ android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface, jnienv

i have a textview in xml file with "tv" id

if i declare

```
TextView tv ;
tv= findViewByID(R.id.tv);
```

then i can call setText Method with this part

```
           extern "C"
        JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
        Java_org_lotka_brilliance_activity_MainActivity_textViewInit(JNIEnv *env, jobject 
            thiz) {
            jclass MainCLass =  env->FindClass("org/lotka/brilliance/activity/MainActivity");
            jclass TextViewClass = env->FindClass("android/widget/TextView");
            jfieldID tvfieild = env->GetFieldID(MainCLass , "tv", 
            "Landroid/widget/TextView;");
            jmethodID tvsettext = env->GetMethodID(TextViewClass , "setText", " 
            (Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V");
            jobject jobject1 = env->GetObjectField(thiz , tvfieild);
            env->CallVoidMethod(jobject1 ,tvsettext , env->NewStringUTF("hello from jni"));
        }
```

im using the TextView which is declared in java part , now the question is that , if i want to find TextView  id in jni what should i do ??

Comment: Call the same methods as the Java code, but through JNI. It's not clear exactly what you're having trouble with since you've already written code for calling another method.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a generated class `com.your.package.R.id` which contains a bunch of `static int`s with the view IDs. So it's just a matter of reading the particular field you're interested in, and then calling `findViewById` to get the `TextView`.

I'm not sure why anyone would want to manipulate their app's views in this cumbersome way, but it can be done:

```
jclass idClass = env->FindClass("com/your/package/R$id");
jfieldID tvField = env->GetStaticFieldID(idClass, "tv", "I");
jint tvId = env->GetStaticIntField(idClass, tvField);

// thiz is a jobject corresponding to the calling Activity instance
jmethodID findViewById = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(thiz), "findViewById", "(I)Landroid/view/View;");
jobject tv = env->CallObjectMethod(thiz, findViewById, tvId);
jmethodID setText = env->GetMethodID(env->GetObjectClass(tv), "setText", "(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)V");
env->CallVoidMethod(tv, setText, env->NewStringUTF("Hello from JNI!"));
```